can I use cooler with LGA1200 or LGA115x support on motherboard with a LGA775 socket?
I have a motherboard (Asus P5B-VM SE) with a LGA775 socket.
can I use cooler with support for LGA1200, LGA1151, LGA1150, LGA1155 or LGA1156 on this motherboard .
I want to buy a DeepCool GAMMAXX 300 Fury ,but the instruction does not list compatibility with the LGA775 socket.
The wiki is telling that LGA775 and LGA1155 is not interchangeable.
GAMMA ARCHER
GAMMAXX 300 FURY


So which (one) socket are you asking about exactly? Your motherboard doesn’t support all of those sockets.

His motherboard is LGA 775 - most third party heatsinks tend to have fairly broad compatibility for more 'modern' heatsinks.

@JourneymanGeek - I know the author's current socket is LGA775. They are asking if their cooler is compatible with a different socket. I am asking which of those four different sockets they are asking about since they are not interchangeable.

Oh, the coolers are vaguely universal. I have a pile of spare cooler mount parts for 'different' processor sockets from a recent build. The cooler will support all with minor changes/adjustments. I think (citation needed) that LGA 115x share a common mount at the very least

a motherboard for intel LGA  have only "holes". any base system (in theory) can be using. some glue or screws...

It depends on the cooler - and the style of mount. Most third party heatsinks are somewhat universal, with different brackets, and mounting wings allowing for broadish compatibility. LGA 115x heatsinks are 75mm between the mounting holes, whole LGA 775 are 72mm - as per this reddit post. Most tower heatsinks would come with different wings and mounts for different processors
'Fortunately' - this seems to use the 'ring' style mount that's common to many heatsinks,

 source 
and you may be able to replace just the bracket (I did a search for lga 775 bracket on aliexpress) for compatibility if you absolutely need to use this cooler. Notice the oval cutouts over the round ones. In theory, I guess You could modify the stock ones slightly to fit with a file as well.

source
Personally I'd recommend getting a cooler with actual LGA 775 compatibility
